# How to integrate the deep learning pipeline in pyspark in windows?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to integrate the deep learning pipeline in pyspark using this command but getting error.

- **$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages databricks:spark-deep-learning:1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11**.
- Is there any other way of integrating the deep learning pipeline with pyspark
- When trying to execute this command in jupyter notebook it is giving error

-line 1
SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages databricks:spark-deep-learning:1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax